# New indexes in MERGE_MYISAM tables takes a lot of time to come into memory when old entries are replaced with newer ones.Is partitioning a better idea

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a MERGE_MYISAM table(3 tables merged). Tables have entries of last 5 days, last 5-10 days, last 10-15 days respectively. Select queries are on column -:id and deletion takes place on the basis of date. If i create a table and create 3 partitions(range) on date select queries will be slow as select happens on id and if partitions are created on the basis of id delete queries will take time. Is there any other beneficial way to create partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deleting a whole day at a time?  Or a whole 5 days?

I would seriously consider daily partitions split by `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` and use a daily `DROP PARTITION` (which is *much* faster than `DELETE`) and `REORGANIZE PARTITION`.

I discuss the details [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

And, I would move to InnoDB.  [See tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).

Comment: I am deleting a whole 5 days at a time

Comment: Then I recommend 5 partitions, 3 of 5 days each, one empty starter, and one empty "future".  My tips explain why.  Note that the partition you are writing to will start empty and grow until it has 5 days' worth, then get shifted.  It is only briefly "the last 5 days".  However `SELECTs` don't care (except for performance) which partition the records are in.

Comment: If your queries really do ask for "the last 5 days", then it would really be better to have daily partitions (~17 total) so that "partition pruning" will pick only 5 1-day partitions instead of 2 5-day partitions.

Comment: I am not clear on what your performance question is, so I cannot say whether partitioning is better or just different.

Comment: select queries are not on date but on another id(primary key). These selects will run on whole table as table is partitioned on range(date).So the performance of select queries cannot be enhanced.Can it?

Comment: Are you doing a 'point query'?  That is one `id` to get one row?  If so, partitioning has a small impact on performance -- it will check all partitions for the desired `id`.

Comment: Can you purge on `id` instead of `date`?  `PARTITION BY RANGE(id)...` is possible, although unusual.  Then `SELECT ... WHERE id = ...` would do "partition pruning" to pick the correct partition, then pick the row.